# level 2 c-mex function input return wrong value

Tags: c++, matlab, simulink, mex, s-function

I have a TLC generated mexfunction with 2 inputs and 0 output. input 1 is unsigned char and input 2 is unsigned int.

When I try to get input values with:

```
unsigned char *u1 = ssGetInputPortSignal(S,0);     (uint8)    
unsigned int  *u2 = ssGetInputPortSignal(S,1);     (uint16)

mexPrintf("value1 %d\n",*u1);
mexPrintf("value2 %d\n",*u2);
```

why `u2` depends on `u1`?

for example:   in simulink the input `port #1 = 2;` ⇒ `*u1= 2;`

but            in simulink the input `port #2 = 1000;` ⇒ `*u2= *u2 +(*u1*65636);`

I see this in `mexprint`..

I get `u2` with a factor depends on the first input port

I set `InputPortRequiredContiguous`  and `InputPortDirectFeedThrough` to 1.

Comment: There's a preview box provided so you can properly format your question before posting it. You say input 2 is `unsigned int`, but seem to also indicate that it is `uint16`. Which is it? If it is `uint16`, then your problem probably is that `unsigned int` is 32-bit and you're reading the memory location where `u1` is stored. Use `unsigned short *u2 = ssGetInputPortSignal(S,1);`. Or better yet, use the fixed width types that mex defines - `uint16_T *u2 = ssGetInputPortSignal(S,1);`

Comment: Thanks for reply !   originally i have a typedef for u1 and u2 so it looks this way:                        typedef  unsigned char  FaultC                                                                                                        typdef unsigned int  addData                                                                                                            FaultC *u1 = (FaultC*) ssGetInputPortSignal(S,0);                                                                         addData  *u2 = (addData*) ssGetInputPortSignal(S,1);       (types are registered)

Comment: sorry for the bad format, quite new here.

Comment: You should add details to your question by clicking the *edit* button below it. Change your `typedef`s to `typedef uint8_T FaultC; typedef uint16_T addData;`, hopefully that'll fix your problem.

Comment: thanks all, will try! i thought unsigned int is 16bit, but now its clear that this is minimum 16bit and thats not equal:))